# How to make a scroll bar to show all the fetch videos in php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, video

I'm currently working on a video project in which I'm fetching videos from the database and showing the relative and remaining ones of the same course at the sidebar. As the number of videos can be increased and then it would expand the page to show themselves.

Like you can see on the below image.

[image]

I was wondering that how can i have a scroll bar to show the remaining videos so that the page length can not be disturbed like you can see on youtube playlist page.

Answer (score 0):

Added a CSS 3 Style and it worked for me like a charm!

```
 style=" height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;"
```